# How should I give upvotes to questions?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

I have seen a few questions which are not very clear, repeated, and sometimes not very important, but having 5 to 10 upvotes.

How should I decide on when to upvote these kind of questions?

Comment: Follow your consience. If it makes you feel dirty then don't vote it up.

Answer (score 8):

I tend to upvote on the clarity of the question:

- Does it lay out the context of the question precisely but succinctly?
- If it mentions an error, does it give details?
- Does it contain code to reproduce the problem, ideally in a short but complete program?
- Does it ask a specific, answerable question?
- Has the questioner paid attention to spelling, grammar and formatting? (i.e. is the presentation good?)

Then about the question topic itself:

- Is it interesting and unusual?
- Does it surprise me (e.g. showing a bit of C# doing something I wouldn't expect it to)?
- Do I think other people ought to know more about this area?

Comment: I've been known to upvote a question *just because* it included a small sample with both expected and actual output, even if the rest of the question was crap.

Comment: Just a reminder. There are a lot of non-native English speakers on stackoverflow like me. Spelling and grammar may be difficult for us, so don't be too tough on those points.

Comment: @Lucas: It's definitely harder for non-native English speakers, but often people clearly haven't made any effort at all. Worse still is using texting abbreviations in questions :(

Comment: @Lucas, +1 thei realy r so cruel to us poor :(  i know english bad why dwnvote?

Comment: @Pavel Shved: ur english sux!

Answer (score 6):

- If you see yourself asking the same question - upvote it +1.
- If you don't know the answer for this question, and you would like to know  - upvote it +1.

Comment: +1, Two of the exact standards I use.

Answer (score 5):

My suggestions...

- If the question is helpful to you, upvote it.
- If the question isn't clear or helpful, don't upvote it.
- If the question is a duplicate, don't upvote it. Upvote the original instead (if you find it helpful).
- If the question is "not very important", silly, off-topic, etc., don't upvote it. You may even want to *downvote* it.
- **Most importantly**, don't just upvote because everyone else is. There are already too many people who upvote nonsense questions.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to many other suggestions, **upvote a question you answered**.  Most likely, if you decided to invest your time into answering, the question was worth it, wasn't it?

Comment: But I only get 30 votes per day! More seriously, there can be a question which I am capable of answering but which still wasn't a particularly good question.

Comment: @Jon, actually, I didn't say about every question; nor I said about every question you are *capable* to answer.

Comment: Okay, to restate: There can be a question where I want to help the questioner and am capable of doing so - and so I *do* answer. That doesn't mean I necessarily think it's a good question. That happens sufficiently often that I wouldn't say your "most likely" applies.